# Convert single entity to an array

Tags: symfony

What is the most efficient way to convert my Symfony2 entity to an array ? Entity contains protected fields with setters/getters. Is it possible to do with `JMSSerializer` ?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Using this bundle is the most efficient way to convert Entities to serialized format. Moreover, it's recommended by Sensio Labs.

To serialize You need only to install, configure this bundle and then:

```
$serializer = JMS\Serializer\SerializerBuilder::create()->build();
$serializer->serialize($object, 'json');
```

And deserialize:

```
$serializer = JMS\Serializer\SerializerBuilder::create()->build();
$object = $serializer->deserialize($jsonData, 'MyNamespace\MyObject', 'json');
```

Nothing more.

You can also use it to convert an object to an array:

```
$serializer = JMS\Serializer\SerializerBuilder::create()->build();
$array = $serializer->toArray($object);
```

Also, you can prevent infinite recursion using serialization groups:

```
$serializer = JMS\Serializer\SerializerBuilder::create()->build();
$context = \JMS\Serializer\SerializationContext::create();
$context->setGroups($groups);
$serializer->serialize($object, 'json', $context);
```

Regards

Comment: Sure, but you explained serialization to a `json` format. I would like to normalize it to an array.

Comment: I get: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: @hsz
        `$jmsSerializer = SerializerBuilder::create()->build();
        $data = $jmsSerializer->toArray($entities);`

Comment: Do not forget to add @Serializer\Expose annotation for properties.

Comment: It works fine with an `ArrayCollection` but when i try to use `toArray()` with a single entity I received this error: `The input data of type "boolean" did not convert to an array, but got a result of type "boolean".`. Do you know why?

Answer (score 13):

If you have not installed Symfony Serializer Component.

install it `composer require symfony/serializer`

then just convert any entity to array as follows.

```
 $serializer = new Serializer(array(new ObjectNormalizer()));
 $data = $serializer->normalize($result, null, array('attributes' => 
   array('success','type','result','errorMessage')));
```

and the output will be,

```
$data = array:[ "success" => true "errorMessage" => null "result" => "1" "type" => "url" ]
```

Comment: Perfect answer. Thank you :)

Answer (score 10):

Using JMSSerializer for such a simple task seems like an overkill to me. I would use [Symfony Serializer Component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html). The demo page shows how to serialize an entity to JSON.

If you just want to put it to array, you don't need serialization at all, you could just instantiate `GetSetMethodNormalizer` and use it since component uses arrays as normalized format.

Comment: What about lazy-load many-to-many attributes? It's not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can also just create a public routine in the entity itself which is similar to what serializer is doing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Serializer Component:

```
$person = new Person();
$person->setName('foo');
$person->setAge(99);

$serializer = new Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer([new ObjectNormalizer()]);
var_dump($serializer->normalize($person));
```

See the documentation: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#serializing-an-object

Also, you can configure the DI globally

```
App.ObjectNormalizer:
    alias: Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ObjectNormalizer

Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer:
    arguments:
        $normalizers:
            0: '@App.ObjectNormalizer'
```

and then simply call:

```
var_dump($serializer->normalize($person));
```